Low Disk Space on "Fylesystem root"
I installed Ubuntu 22.04 and right after I used it 3-4 times this "Low Disk Space on Fylesysem root" appeared. How can I expand this partition?


Interesting partitioning choices, 32 G swap and 15 G /. Probably your easiest fix is to shrink the gigantic swap partition and expand the / into where it was. Or delete the swap partition completely and set up a swapfile.

Does this answer your question? The volume "Filesystem Root" has only 533.9 MB disk space remaining and How do I resize root partition?

I was told swap needed to be twice the size of my RAM which is 16 GB thats why I put 32 GB. If I shrink that partition to 16 GB por example and I add that to the / part I dont know if that would be enough since the previous 15 GB fulled extremely soon and without adding new files

Nobody using a current Ubuntu told you that as we use a swap FILE and have been for years and years. / should be 20Gb or more. 20Gb with no snap and no server software. With snap 30 or 40 willl be better. Remove the swap part, add the 32 to / and you will be fine.
